# Where are kdb_* functions used?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

There are a lot of `kdb_*` functions under Linux Kernel source path `/kernel/debug/kdb`, like the function `kdb_lsmod`. I wonder where these functions are used, and how to invoke these functions when debugging a Linux Kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions mostly define commands that you can directly run from KDB. You can see the commands defined in [`kdb_inittab()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/debug/kdb/kdb_main.c#L2779). For example the `kdb_lsmod()` function you are talking about can be invoked through the [`lsmod`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/debug/kdb/kdb_main.c#L2856) command in KDB.